# in numpy, delete a row where an entry in a column cannot be converted to a float

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array in numpy, and in the process of inspecting it, I realize that some of the values in one particular column contain strings of gibberish.

For example, the suspect column is the second column, and it looks something like this:

```
['Joe', '200.00']
['Fred', 'adfdfddfds']
['Zhu', '5000.00']
['text_ok_here', '10.10']
```

(please note that the `dtype` is string)

I would like to ultimately have:

```
['Joe', '200.00']
['Zhu', '5000.00']
['text_ok_here', '10.10']
```

I need to delete any full row that has a string that I can't convert to float, hanging out in my particular column.

Originally, I was thinking I could just iterate through the column, collect the indices that match the offending entries, and use that to subset my original array.

Something along these lines:

```
for entry in my particular column:
    if <entry is a string, not a float>
        <delete that whole row of the matrix>
```

But this won't work because everything is a string anyways.

I'm stuck with the problem of converting types but I have no straightforward way to test for the gibberish.  Further, even if I did find the correct indices, I'm unsure how to go about the subsetting.

I feel like this is pretty common stuff -- cleaning up an array, but having a surprisingly difficult time in accomplishing this.

Any advice/philosophy etc would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: However, `'text_ok_here'` can't be converted to a `number`, shouldn't it be removed as well?

Comment: It is only the second column that has the values that we don't want.  The first column must stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be really import to know what `dtype` your data is in, but if it is `float` or `int` or any of the number like `dtype`s, `boolean` indexing will be enough

The data file:

```
<temp.txt>
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 bad
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 bad
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Solution:

```
In [9]:

A=np.genfromtxt('temp.txt')
A
Out[9]:
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.],
       [  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.],
       [  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,  nan],
       [  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.],
       [  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.],
       [  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,  nan],
       [  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.],
       [  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.]])
In [10]:

np.isfinite(A).all(1) #only TRUE when all the cells in the row are valid number
Out[10]:
array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [11]:

A[np.isfinite(A).all(1)]
Out[11]:
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.]])
```

## Edit

If the `array` is already in `string`, this might be the easiest:

```
In [40]:

%%file temp.txt
1000.00 200.00
4000.00 adfdfddfds
20.00 5000
text_ok_here 5000
Overwriting temp.txt
In [53]:

A=np.genfromtxt('temp.txt', dtype=str)
B=np.genfromtxt('temp.txt')
In [55]:

A[np.isfinite(B[:,1])]
Out[55]:
array([['1000.00', '200.00'],
       ['20.00', '5000'],
       ['text_ok_here', '5000']], 
      dtype='|S12')
```

Basically read the data into `A` as an `array` of `string`s; into `B` as `float` and `NAN` wherever can't be converted to a valid number, then get a slice of `A` based on `B`.

Comment: CT Zhu, I have an array of strings.

Comment: But if that is case, `if <entry is None or a string>`, wouldn't it be `True` for every cell? Because the cells are in `str`? What is the criteria for gibberish in this case?

Comment: You are absolutely right.  Even my pseudocode is not working!!

Comment: Anyway to test if a cell is gibberish? Other than an eyeball test? :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this.  Iterate through the numerical indices of the rows checking your condition.  If the condition is not met, add the index to the list `keep` which contains the row indices to keep.  Then you can slice your array with the list `keep` to obtain an array with only the rows that did not satisfy the condition for elimination.  To slice the array `a` using the list `keep`, do `a[keep]`.  If you wish to overwrite your original array do `a = a[keep]`.  Here is an example which prints the array before slicing, the list of indices to keep, and the array after slicing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy

a = numpy.array([['foo', 2, 3], [4, 5, None], [7, 8, 'bar'], [10, None, 12]])
print(a)
keep = []
j = 2
for i in range(0, a.shape[0]) :
    if not(a[i, j] is None or isinstance(a[i, j], basestring)) :
        keep.append(i)
print keep
a2 = a[keep]
print(a2)
```

Comment: Mark:  this is a fantastic answer.  I regret to say that I have edited my question as I've gotten more familiar with the problem I'm facing and your excellent solution doesn't apply.  My apologies.

Comment: No worries.  Good luck with your application!